# Casting a parameter mock object to another object using Mockito

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

I have a method to test, that begins following:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    contextString = adapter.getItem(info.position);
        /.../
    }
```

I would like to test it using Mockito, but if I declare menuInfo like this:

```
@Mock ContextMenuInfo menuInfo
```

then I cannot compile the following statement:

```
Mockito.when(menuInfo.position).thenReturn(1);
```

since it is not valid for `ContextMenuInfo` object. I cannot declare my object as `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` class, since then I get an error during run time.

I know that in Mockito it is possible that a mock implements multiple interfaces, but the same does not apply to classes. How would it be possible to test the method I shown above?

Comment: *I get an error*: which error?

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito works by using Java *inheritance* to replace the implementations of methods on a class. However, it looks like `position` is a *field* on [`AdapterContextMenuInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html), which means that Mockito can't mock it for you.

Luckily, AdapterContextMenuInfo has [a public constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html#AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo%28android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), so you don't have to 
mock it—you can just create one for the test and pass it into your method.

```
@Test public void contextMenuShouldWork() {
  ContextMenuInfo info =
      new AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo(view, position, id);
  systemUnderTest.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, info);

  /* assert success here */
}
```

**If you're ever stuck in this pattern for a class that you can't directly mock or instantiate**, consider creating a helper class that you *can* mock:

```
class MyHelper {

  /** Used for testing. */
  int getPositionFromContextMenuInfo(ContextMenuInfo info) {
    return ((AdapterContextMenuInfo) info).position;
  }
}
```

Now you can refactor your View to use that:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  /** visible for testing */
  MyHelper helper = new MyHelper();

  public void onCreateContextMenu(
      ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    int position = helper.getPositionFromContextMenuInfo(menuInfo);
    // ...
  }
}
```

...and then mock *the helper* in your test.

```
/** This is only a good idea in a world where you can't instantiate the type. */
@Test public void contextMenuShouldWork() {
  ContextMenuInfo info = getSomeInfoObjectYouCantChange();

  MyHelper mockHelper = Mockito.mock(MyHelper.class);
  when(mockHelper.getPositionFromContextMenu(info)).thenReturn(42);
  systemUnderTest.helper = mockHelper;
  systemUnderTest.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, info);

  /* assert success here */
}
```

**There is one other option, involving a refactor:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreateContextMenu(
      ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
        (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    onCreateContextMenuImpl(info.position);
  }

  /** visible for testing */
  void onCreateContextMenuImpl(int position) {
    // the bulk of the code goes here
  }
}

@Test public void contextMenuShouldWork() {
  systemUnderTest.onCreateContextMenuImpl(position);

  /* assert success here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very throughout answer. I implemented in this case the first option. However, the second option is extremely useful and I need it for another situation. There I still have a problem of setting the field value for the mock. Ie: I mock a helper class and can pass it as a parameter for the testable class, but how could I for example set a field value in the mockito manner of when(myHelper.position).thenReturn((float)100)?

Comment: Updated my answer with details about how to mock the helper. Hope that makes things clearer! :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, the suggested solutions are all very well described :)

Answer (score 5):

May be use mockito's `extraInterfaces` option

```
        @Mock(extraInterfaces=AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.class) 
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo
```

and then mock it like

```
Mockito.doReturn(1).when((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position
```